# the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges

Tags: nginx, mamp

I had to remove a folder ON LOCAL COMPUTER with my project (because of corrupted git files) and re-git clone it (successfully).
It runs on MAMP's NGINX server.

Now when I am trying to open project's main page in broswer and get "HTTP ERROR 500".

/Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_error.log:

> 2018/06/08 18:58:29 [warn] 3218#0: the "user" directive makes sense
>   only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in
>   /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf:7

/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf:7:

```
user                         sergeyfomin staff;
```

(sergeyfomin is my User name on my Mac)

I guess it has something to do with user-priviliges I need to re-set on my project after git-cloning it?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The 500 error and the log warning are probably unrelated, since the warning says that it just ignored the directive. You'll probably have to dig elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: thanks! yes, I just checked /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log - and there is "[10-Aug-2018 13:44:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/sergeyfomin/code/first/vendor/composer/../psy/psysh/src/Psy/functions.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.27/lib/php') in /Users/sergeyfomin/code/first/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66"